# Sum of all vectors of variables with common prefix

Tags: r

Is it possible to sum all vector variables with a common prefix ?

Exemple:

```
x1 <- c(1,2,3)
x2 <- c(4,5,6)
  .
  .
  .
xn <- c(n,n,n)

y = x1 + x2 + ... xn
```

The number of variables `xn` (ie with prefix `x`) is only known at runtime.

Comment: How did you create all those variables in the first place? Seems like they should have been in a list. Probably better to fix the problem at the cause then clean up after the mess after the fact.

Comment: R runtime is embedded inside a Java runtime. Variables in R are dynamically instanciated from java env.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `y` has the same dimension as `x`, you could try capturing all the variables into the list and apply a summation operation.

```
> x2 <- c(4,5,6)
> x1 <- c(1,2,3)
> ls(pattern = "^x\\d+$") # this is regex for finding "x" and "digits", 
                          # ^ is start of string, $ is end of string
[1] "x1" "x2"
> sapply(ls(pattern = "^x\\d+$"), get, simplify = FALSE)
$x1
[1] 1 2 3

$x2
[1] 4 5 6

> out <- sapply(ls(pattern = "^x\\d+$"), get, simplify = FALSE)
> Reduce("+", out)
[1] 5 7 9
```

You can also use `mget` as suggested by @LyzandeR's, especially if fancy one-liners.

```
Reduce("+", mget(ls(pattern = "^x\\d+$")))
```

Comment: One-liner version is even better

Answer (score 2):

You can check an example:

```
xx <- 1
xx2 <- 2
xx3 <- 3

#get the names of the variables containing xx
vars <- ls(pattern = 'xx')
#mget will get the variables from the names, unlist will add them in an atomic vector
sum(unlist(mget(vars)))
#[1] 6
```

Answer (score 0):

A very naive solution could be:

```
# first 2 vectors are of interest
x1 <- c(1,2,3)
x2 <- c(4,5,6)

# answer doesn't need to have z sum in it
z <- c(7,8,9)

# create a dummy answer vector, initialize it will all 0; length will be the length of single vector that we are adding
answer<-rep(0,length(x1))

# loop through each variable in current environment
for (var in ls()){
    # see if variable name begins with x
    if (startsWith(var,'x')){
        # add it to our answer
        answer = answer + get(var)
    }
}
# print the answer
print(answer)
```

Comment: This solution assumes there are no other variables starting with `x` in the workspace.

Comment: wouldn't every solution that uses ls() assume the same?